# Instantiating a 2d Vec in a Struct?

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble instantiating a vec when using a constructor to return a new struct object. The syntax I've tried (using collect() improperly, probably) spat out a ton of compiler errors.

```
fn main() {
    let level = Level::new();
}

struct Level {
    tiles: Vec<Vec<Tile>>
}

struct Tile {
    idx: i32
}

impl Level {
    fn new() -> Level {
        Level {
            tiles: {
            let mut t = Vec::new();
            let mut t2 = Vec::new();
            for x in range(0, 80) {
                for y in range(0, 24) {
                    t2.push(Tile::new(x, y));
                }
                t.push(t2);
            }
            t
        }
    }
}

impl Tile {
    fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Tile {
        Tile { pos: Point { x: x, y: y } }
    }
}

struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}
```

I get these errors:

```
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:47:25: 47:27 error: use of moved value: `t2`
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:47                 t2.push(Tile::new(x, y));
                                                     ^~
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:49:28: 49:30 note: `t2` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<game::dungeon::level::Tile>`, which is non-copyable
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:49                     t.push(t2);
                                                        ^~
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:49:28: 49:30 error: use of moved value: `t2`
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:49                     t.push(t2);
                                                        ^~
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:49:28: 49:30 note: `t2` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<game::dungeon::level::Tile>`, which is non-copyable
src/game/dungeon/level/mod.rs:49                     t.push(t2);
                                                        ^~
```

Comment: What syntax have you been using?

Comment: I'll update the post with what I just tried

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Updated post again with errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're doing it incorrectly. The similar code will also be incorrect in C/C++, BTW.

```
        let mut t = Vec::new();
        let mut t2 = Vec::new();
        for x in range(0, 80) {
            for y in range(0, 24) {
                t2.push(Tile::new());
            }
            t.push(t2);
        }
```

The problem is, you're always pushing into the same `t2` in the inner loop and then you're always pushing the same `t2` into `t`. The latter is a violation of ownership semantics, so Rust compiler correctly tells you about using a moved value.

The idiomatic approach is to use iterators and it could look like this:

```
(0..80).map(|_| (0..24).map(|_| Tile::new()).collect()).collect()
```

If you need to access indices you can use `map()` closure arguments:

```
(0..80).map(|x| (0..24).map(|y| Tile::new(x, y)).collect()).collect()
```

The compiler should automatically deduce the desired type of `collect()` result.

Answer (score 3):

Vladimir's answer is really nice, however I have a feeling that the functional style might hide the error here.

You are actually not far from the solution; the issue is simply that you cannot reuse the same `t2` at each iteration of the outer loop. The simplest transformation, therefore, is to create `t2` **inside** the outer loop:

```
impl Level {
    fn new() -> Level {
        Level {
            tiles: {
            let mut t = Vec::new();
            for x in range(0, 80) {
                let mut t2 = Vec::new(); // Moved!
                for y in range(0, 24) {
                    t2.push(Tile::new(x, y));
                }
                t.push(t2);
            }
            t
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the "functional style" is *the* idiomatic approach now, that is, in the future most of the code will be written like that :)

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: I agree, and it is so much neater and more concise too; however I am afraid it might be too big a step up from the OP's current code so I prefer to point down *exactly* what the current problem is on top of recommending a change in style (or I should mean, letting YOU recommend a change in style).

Comment: I ended up using Vladimir's solution, but yours helped me understand exactly what I was doing wrong - thanks!